# Injecting an Interface implementation in Swing objects

Tags: java, swing

I have defined a `class InfoAction implements java.swing.Action` that needs to retrieve some information from its calling context in order to execute itself. For this I have defined an interface for providing those information:

```
public interface InfoProvider {
    Info getInfo();
}
```

The `actionPerformed` in the InfoAction class looks like

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Info info=e.getSource().getInfo();
    // ... treat Info ...
}
```

Then I want to create various Swing objects using these actions, every Swing object providing its own context to the action.

```
InfoAction infoAction = MyApp.getInstance().getAction(MyApp.RENAME_ACTION); // Retrieving one action
JButton button = new JButton(infoAction); // TODO: inject the InfoProvider interface
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(infoAction); // TODO: inject the InfoProvider interface
```

I'm stuck at how to add to those swing objects the InfoProvider interface.

Naively I tried to write

```
InfoAction infoAction = MyApp.getInstance().getAction(MyApp.RENAME_ACTION);
JButton button = new JButton(infoAction) implements InfoProvider {
    Info getInfo() {
        return MyGui.this.getInfo();
        }
    };
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(infoAction)  implements InfoProvider {
    Info getInfo() {
        return MyGui.this.getInfo();
        }
    };
```

But this is not a valid code.

I'd like to avoid creating sub-classes of all the Swing pieces such as
`private class InfoButton extends JButton implements InfoProvider {...}`, `private class InfoMenuItem extends JMenuItem implements InfoProvider {...}`.

So I wonder what are the other options to do this while keeping a clean code ?
Would working with reflection a good option ? Getting rid of the interface and testing if the actionEvent.getSource() has a getInfo() method ?

PS: I'm working with Java8

Comment: I don't understand the overall objective of your project.  Are you constructing a GUI builder?  Why can't you separate the construction of the GUI from adding values to the Swing components?

Comment: Reflection will not make the code cleaner. As you want to `extend` the functionality of an existing class, the cleanest way in my opinion is to create sub-classes which then implement your desired functionality

Comment: @Holger : corrected. In the remaining of the code, the InfoAction a provided by an external class.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'm constructing a fat-client software. Where there are several ways to reach the same action. I want the define the action once. With its code, its label, its icon. Each ways to activate the action has to provide to the action some context (e.g. if the Action is "Move Files", which files in this context must be moved). So I'm trying to add to each Swing object a way to provide that context, by injecting into it that ÌnfoProvider` interface.

Comment: Okay, using your comment example, you create a `MoveFilesAction` class extending `AbstractAction`.  You can instantiate this class from several Swing components.  Your application model would hold the file names or `File` class instances that your `MoveFilesAction` class needs.  Your Swing components have nothing to do with the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to specialize every component supporting actions (or timer or other sources of action events). Instead, create one specialized `Action` implementation to mediate between the component/event source and the actual action. E.g.

```java
public class InfoProviderAction implements Action, InfoProvider {
    final PropertyChangeSupport listeners = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    final PropertyChangeListener relay = ev -> listeners.firePropertyChange(
                        ev.getPropertyName(), ev.getOldValue(), ev.getNewValue());
    final Action target;
    final InfoProvider actualProvider;

    public InfoProviderAction(Action target, InfoProvider actualProvider) {
        this.target = target;
        this.actualProvider = actualProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        target.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(
            this, e.getID(), e.getActionCommand(), e.getWhen(), e.getModifiers()));
    }

    @Override
    public Info getInfo() {
        return actualProvider.getInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        boolean hadListeners = listeners.hasListeners(null);
        listeners.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        if(!hadListeners) target.addPropertyChangeListener(relay);
    }

    @Override
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        boolean hadListeners = listeners.hasListeners(null);
        listeners.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
        if(hadListeners && !listeners.hasListeners(null))
            target.removePropertyChangeListener(relay);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return target.isEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
        target.setEnabled(b);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(String key) {
        return target.getValue(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void putValue(String key, Object value) {
        target.putValue(key, value);
    }
}
```

Then, your `MyGui` class can use it like

```java
InfoAction infoAction = MyApp.getInstance().getAction(MyApp.RENAME_ACTION);
infoAction = new InfoProviderAction(infoAction, this::getInfo);// inject the InfoProvider
JButton button = new JButton(infoAction);
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(infoAction);
```

The component will see the `InfoProviderAction` as its action, which will exhibit the same properties and behavior as the wrapped action. Whereas the actual action will see the `InfoProviderAction` as the even source, implementing the `InfoProvider` interface as expected.

Problems could arise if the action expects the source to be a component. But actions should not assume this, as it would cause problems with `Timer` or global key bindings as event sources.

Answer (score 1):

There is something you can use with Swing:

- [JComponent.putClientProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)
- [JComponent.getClientProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getClientProperty-java.lang.Object-)

When you build your object, you can configure it:

```
class ComponentFactory {
  public static <T extends JComponent> T configure(T component) {
    // the MyGui.this won't compile here, but it is only to explain
    // what you can do with your current code.
    component.putClientProperty(InfoProvider.class, MyGui.this);
  }
}
```

And build object as in:

```
ComponentFactory.configure(new JButton(infoAction));
```

Or create a static method for it in `ComponentFactory`:

```
ComponentFactory.createButton(infoAction);
```

In your action, you can then read the property:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  Object src = e.getSource();
  if (src instanceof JComponent) {
    JComponent c = (JComponent) src;
    
    Info info = (Info) c.getClientProperty(InfoProvider.class);
    ...
  }

}
```

**Notes:**

Since it is Swing, there is a some chance it requires to be `Serializable` - which I don't think is a problem in 2022.

And that the doc for `putClientProperty` says:

> The clientProperty dictionary **is not intended** to support large scale extensions to JComponent nor should be it considered an alternative to subclassing when designing a new component.

It should be fine for one property, otherwise you would have to use subclassing and implements InfoProvider for each such component.